# can anyone tell me which font is this or how to know fonttype from jpg images

Tags: fonts, truetype, jpgraph

I'm trying to identify the font used in this graphic.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replicate the look of a gas pump receipt? Interesting.

The font is [Ascender Uni Duo](http://www.identifont.com/list?17+id+1+EQ+1+NIV+1+545+1+2Z8V+1+2Z8Y+1+2Z8X+1+21E+5+72Q+6+CF+6) and will run you $165. [Andalé Mono](http://www.identifont.com/list?17+id+0+EQ+1+NIV+1+545+1+2Z8V+1+2Z8Y+1+2Z8X+1+21E+5+72Q+6+CF+6) is similar but has a dotted zero and isn't as narrow. The former would be a better receipt font.

Free san-serif monospaced fonts are available. Have a look at [Liberation Mono](http://www.fontspace.com/category/monospaced?p=2) and [Droid Sans Mono](http://www.fontspace.com/google-android/droid-sans-mono).

Comment: is there any font similar to this font available for free,there is no strict character matching constraint,its ok if some characters change here and there.thanks in advance

Comment: See link in updated answer. Would you mind telling us your use case for this font?